# How to get currently playing item in XBMC?

Tags: json, json-rpc, xbmc

I want to use json/rpc in order to get the currently playing item in the XBMC, I'm using the following commands for all the of player types:

- to getting the Active player :

  `{
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "method": "Player.GetActivePlayers",
      "id": 1
  }`
- And to getting the currently playing item due to the above result:

  `{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "Playlist.GetItems",
  "params": {
      "playlistid": playlist.id,
      "properties": ["title",
      "rating",
      "season",
      "episode",
      "plot",
      "runtime",
      "showtitle",
      "thumbnail",
      "year",
      "genre"]
  },
  "id": 1
  }`

Now, I have three different cases:

1- if the currently playing item is a "**movie**":
every thing works very efficient.

2- if the currently playing item is a "**song**":
the result set contains not only the currently playing song but all the songs of the album that contains the currently playing song.

3- if the currently playing item is a "**tvShow episode**":
the result set is empty like if there is nothing currently playing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "Player.GetItem",
    "params": {
        "properties": [
            "title",
            "album",
            "artist",
            "season",
            "episode",
            "duration",
            "showtitle",
            "tvshowid",
            "thumbnail",
            "file",
            "fanart",
            "streamdetails"
        ],
        "playerid": 1
    },
    "id": "VideoGetItem"
}
```

Check this out for [further API examples](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=JSON-RPC_API/Examples).